# I need to find the value in a two dimensional array using the x and y cordinates

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This is the grid I'm using in my code and I need to find the value which is in the coordinates when I give the x and y coordinates from the Scanner.

```
int [][] grid = {
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
          {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
          {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
          {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
          {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems very easy or you didn't show all your task:
It will be:

int targetValue = grid[x][y]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `grid[y][x]`.

```
public void test(String args[]) {
    int [][] grid = {
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
    };
    System.out.println(getValueAt(grid,4,2));
}

private int getValueAt(int[][] grid, int x, int y) {
    return grid[y][x];
}
```

Sometimes it is the other way around but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do this is via: `int userValue = grid[x][y];`

x value indicates the row you're looking for and y value indicates the column.

In your case with using scanner, the code should look something like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter x value: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter y value: ");
        int y = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(grid[x][y]);
```